# Converting container types?

Tags: type-conversion, kotlin

Maybe I missed something obvious... All over the doc it seems to me that Kotlin has various kinds of sequences, which don't interoperate. Even if it may be inefficient to copy a sequence – when I need to pass it to a function as a semantically same but different type, that can't be helped. So I came up (only for Int and one way) with these constructors and converters:

```
fun IntArray(a: Array<Int>) = IntArray( a.size ) { a[it] }
fun IntArray(c: Collection<Int>) = IntArray( c.size ) { c.elementAt(it) }
fun IntArray(p: IntProgression) = IntArray( p.toList() )
fun IntArray(s: Sequence<Int>) = IntArray( s.toList() )

fun Array<Int>.toIntArray() = IntArray( this )
fun Collection<Int>.toIntArray() = IntArray( this )
fun IntProgression.toIntArray() = IntArray( this )
fun Sequence<Int>.toIntArray() = IntArray( this )

/* If constructors are not desirable:
fun Array<Int>.toIntArray() = IntArray( size ) { get(it) }
fun Collection<Int>.toIntArray() = IntArray( size ) { elementAt(it) }
fun IntProgression.toIntArray() = toList().toIntArray()
fun Sequence<Int>.toIntArray() = toList().toIntArray()*/
```

Is there any reason not to have all such variants, maybe inline, in the standard library? The 3rd one even allows a nice syntax for initialization:

```
val ia = IntArray( 7 .. 11 )
```

Comment: Note: Sequences and arrays are two different things in Kotlin. It seems like you are asking about arrays here, not sequences. This is a sequence: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/index.html

Comment: True, more bewilderment ;-)  Have edited above accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there are functions in stdlib that do the conversions: see [`.toIntArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-int-array.html), which works with `Array<out Int>` and `Collection<Int>`. The other primitive types also have such conversions: [`.toLongArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-long-array.html), [`.toByteArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-byte-array.html) etc.

However, there's no such extension for `IntProgression` and `Sequence<Int>`, and you have to either implement it on your own or use an intermediate array or collection.

Probably the reason for this absence is that you are not encouraged to use arrays in your code except for the performance critical parts, and instead it's idiomatic to use lists and other collections.

---

Also, the three kinds of Kotlin containers, `Collection<T>`, `Sequence<T>` and `Array<T>`, can be converted to each other, see:

- [`.asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html)
- [`.toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) (seems to be missing for `Sequence<T>`)
- [`.toCollection()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-collection.html) (and for `Sequence<T>`: [`.toCollection()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/to-collection.html))

Comment: @zienkikk Thanks to both of you!  Maybe someone should go through helper-functions for completeness and consistency (e.g. get/set/[] vs. only elementAt).  After all I started on this endeavour when I was totally clueless how to get this done.  All variants I tried intuitively lead nowhere.  And coming up with this from the doc, took me a long time.

Comment: How would you implement `Sequence.toTypedArray()`?

Answer (score 2):

`Array<Int>` and `IntArray` don't interoperate because they are very different types. The first maps to `Integer[]` while the second to `int[]`. The primitive `int[]` will be much more efficient because it is contiguously stored whereas the first essentially allocates an array of objects where each slot points at an `Integer` object. Both memory usage and performance will be vastly superior with `int[]`.

Kotlin likes to be explicit about these types of things and as you pointed out, writing your own conversion when you need it takes one line.

PS: Looks like Kotlin does have extension functions to go from `Collection` of numbers to the primitive arrays:

```
public fun Collection<Int>.toIntArray(): IntArray {
    val result = IntArray(size)
    var index = 0
    for (element in this)
        result[index++] = element
    return result
}
```

Comment: Oh, good, seems to be available, after all.  However I wonder where that's documented.  `Collection<Int>` has no page of it's own does is?  Besides it seems much more cumbersome than my 13th line `IntArray( size ) { elementAt(it) }`

Comment: @Daniel I believe a library function implementation is not supposed to be elegant but should be robust and efficient. For example, some collections do not support constant-time random access (e.g. `LinkedList`), so it is preferrable to use a for-loop instead of indices.

Comment: @Daniel As to the docs, these functions are extensions, and, since they are not defined in a class, their docs are nested in the package they are declared in, see the links in the other answer.

Comment: @hotkey actually extensions for a class are listed on that class'es doc page, if the extensions are in the same library.